# Monads: What's the difference between seq and >>=?

Tags: haskell, monads, seq

What's the difference? Does `seq` guarantee more flow conditions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They aren't related at all.

`seq` has the type:

```
seq :: a -> b -> b
```

It is used (as `seq a b`, or `` a `seq` b ``) to evaluate `a` to head normal form, which is a fancy way of saying that it forces the lazy value `a` to be evaluated a little bit. It has nothing to do with monads.

`>>=` is  for sequencing monads. It has the type:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

It is used to get the value from a monadic value and pass it to a function that returns another monadic value. Basically something like:

```
getLine >>= putStrLn
```

which would get a string of input from the command-line and then print it out.

So, basically, no relation at all.

Comment: Hmmm, `seq` might count as something like `(>>)` for some sort of "strict identity monad". Kinda doubt that's what the questioner had in mind though.

Comment: Or maybe the OP is thinking of `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`?

Answer (score 2):

[`seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aseq) is not specific to monads. `seq` is used to force evaluation of its first argument before its second is returned.

Comment: Nope. That was pseq. Seq is just strict.in both of its arguments. There is nothing said about tue order of evaluation.